# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class DBExecuter.Queryjson$valIOConfigclass

Tags: java, json, gson

I am parsing a json string using fromjson method of gson, when I run the parser as standalone java application, it works but when I run it from an EAR, i'm getting this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class DBExecuter.Queryjson$valIOConfigclass. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated

json:

```
{
"code": "code1",
"query": "text",
"type": "10",
"_condqflg": "1",
"_pkgvarflg": "0",
"_IOSerial": "1|2|5",
"_ioConfig": [{
        "_iosl": "1",
        "_iokey": "text",
        "_iotype": "I",
        "_ioflag": "I"
    },
    {
        "_iosl": "2",
        "_iokey": "text",
        "_iotype": "V",
        "_ioflag": "I"
    },
    {
        "_iosl": "3",
        "_iokey": "text",
        "_iotype": "I",
        "_ioflag": "I"
    },
    {
        "_iosl": "4",
        "_iokey": "CLIENT_NUM",
        "_iotype": "I",
        "_ioflag": "1"
    }

],
"_valcfg": [{
        "_cfgsl": "1",
        "_cfgstr": "text",
        "_cfgioSl": "4"
    },
    {
        "_cfgsl": "2",
        "_cfgstr": "text",
        "_cfgioSl": "3|1"
    }
]
},
{
"code": "code2",
"query": "text",
"type": "10",
"_condqflg": "1",
"_pkgvarflg": "0",
"_IOSerial": "1|2|5",
"_ioConfig": [{
        "_iosl": "1",
        "_iokey": "text",
        "_iotype": "I",
        "_ioflag": "I"
    },
    {
        "_iosl": "2",
        "_iokey": "text",
        "_iotype": "V",
        "_ioflag": "I"
    },
    {
        "_iosl": "3",
        "_iokey": "text",
        "_iotype": "I",
        "_ioflag": "I"
    },
    {
        "_iosl": "4",
        "_iokey": "CLIENT_NUM",
        "_iotype": "I",
        "_ioflag": "1"
    }
],
"_valcfg": [{
        "_cfgsl": "1",
        "_cfgstr": "text",
        "_cfgioSl": "4"
    },
    {
        "_cfgsl": "2",
        "_cfgstr": "text",
        "_cfgioSl": "3|1"
    }
]
}
```

parser class:

```
public class JSONparser extends DBImplementManager {

    ArrayList<Queryjson> jsonParseResult = new ArrayList<Queryjson>();
    HashMap<String, Queryjson> _querymap = new HashMap<>();

    public LinkedHashMap<String,Queryjson> _pgmValmap =new LinkedHashMap<String,Queryjson>();


    private JSONparser()
    {
        //load(pgmid);
    }

    private static JSONparser instance;

    public static JSONparser getInstance()
    {
        if(instance==null)
        {
            synchronized(JSONparser.class){
                if(instance==null)
                {
                    instance=new JSONparser();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void load(String pgmid, String modid)
    {
        try {
             InputStream input = Thread.currentThread()
                        .getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
             Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
             jsonParseResult = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Queryjson>>(){}.getType());

            System.out.println("json loading begin");
            if (jsonParseResult != null ) {
                for (Queryjson _query : jsonParseResult) {
                    _querymap.put(_query.getCode(), _query);
                    _pgmValmap.put(pgmid+"_"+_query.getCode(), _query);
                    System.out.println("Result: " + _query.getCode());

                   // _query.loadmaps();

                }
            }
            System.out.println("json loading done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

pojo class:
public class Queryjson {

```
public Queryjson(){

}
private String code;
private String query;
private String type;
private String _condqflg;
private String _pkgvarflg;
private String _IOSerial;
private valIOConfigclass[] _ioConfig;
private valCFGclass[] _valcfg;

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public String getQuery() {
    return query;
}
public void setQuery(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String getcondqflg() {
    return _condqflg;
}
public void setcondqflg(String _condqflg) {
    this._condqflg = _condqflg;
}
public String getpkgvarflg() {
    return _pkgvarflg;
}
public void setpkgvarflg(String _pkgvarflg) {
    this._pkgvarflg = _pkgvarflg;
}
public String get_IOSerial() {
    return _IOSerial;
}
public void set_IOSerial(String _IOSerial) {
    this._IOSerial = _IOSerial;
}
public valIOConfigclass[] get_ioConfig() {
    return _ioConfig;
}
public void set_ioConfig(valIOConfigclass[] _ioConfig) {
    this._ioConfig = _ioConfig;
}

public valCFGclass[] get_valcfg() {
    return _valcfg;
}
public void set_valcfg(valCFGclass[] _valcfg) {
    this._valcfg = _valcfg;
}

public class valIOConfigclass {
    private String _iosl;
    private String _iokey;
    private String _iotype;
    private String _ioflag;

    public valIOConfigclass()
    {

    }
    public String get_iosl() {
        return _iosl;
    }
    public void set_iosl(String _iosl) {
        this._iosl = _iosl;
    }
    public String get_iokey() {
        return _iokey;
    }
    public void set_iokey(String _iokey) {
        this._iokey = _iokey;
    }
    public String get_iotype() {
        return _iotype;
    }
    public void set_iotype(String _iotype) {
        this._iotype = _iotype;
    }
    public String get_ioflag() {
        return _ioflag;
    }
    public void set_ioflag(String _ioflag) {
        this._ioflag = _ioflag;
    }
}
public class valCFGclass{
    private String _cfgsl;
    private String _cfgstr;
    private String _cfgioSl;

    public valCFGclass(){

    }
    public String get_cfgsl() {
        return _cfgsl;
    }
    public void set_cfgsl(String _cfgsl) {
        this._cfgsl = _cfgsl;
    }
    public String get_cfgstr() {
        return _cfgstr;
    }
    public void set_cfgstr(String _cfgstr) {
        this._cfgstr = _cfgstr;
    }
    public String get_cfgioSl() {
        return _cfgioSl;
    }
    public void set_cfgioSl(String _cfgioSl) {
        this._cfgioSl = _cfgioSl;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark your inner classes (valIOConfigclass and valCFGclass) as `static`

Comment: @smootherbug, non-static inner classes belongs to instance of parent class. So deserialiser first try to create inner fields (valIOConfigclass and valCFGclass) but cannot because these classes exists only in Queryjson object and Queryjson variable is not created yet.

Comment: if two objects for my Queryjson class is created, wont the inner static class get affected,like consider the following json, consider the edited json above

Comment: @smootherbug, no. Think about inner static class as an usual one. Check docs about 'inner classes' - I guess it will explain details better than me.

Comment: thanks @Bor Laze, and one more thing
In the above json string, is it possible to parse the "_ioConfig" as an map of key type string and value arraylist type("_iokey","_iotype","_ioflag").
I am using gson parser for parsing, currently im getting this as array of objects and then parsing manually

Comment: @smootherbug, I'm not sure. May be, here will help custom deserialization, but I cannot help with it. Anyway, like for me current solution is quite good.

Comment: But why it doesn't have any problem when I run the parser is standalone Java application